# How to embed font into pdf/a using iText7

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext7

I'm trying to see how to embed fonts into my pdf/a.
I found a lot of answer but using iTextSharp.
In my cas I use iText7 and all I tried gave me the error:
"All the fonts must be embedded..."

I have a ttf file for my font but I didn't find a way to embed it into my pdf to use it...

Could someone help me?
Thanks in advance

kor6k

Comment: Did you read the [tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-7-creating-pdfua-and-pdfa-documents)? Have you tried the PDF/A examples from that tutorial? If so, what didn't work? If not, why didn't you read the tutorial before asking a question?

Comment: How !!! I'm a little ashamed... I read the tutorial long time ago and I didn't see it the font part... Now I see it and I don't understand why I didn't succed; it is very easy... Thanks for your help !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the [tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-7-creating-pdfua-and-pdfa-documents) and as indicated by the error you mention ("All the fonts must be embedded"), you need to embed the fonts.

You are probably not defining a font, in which case the *standard Type 1* font Helvetica will be used. These *standard Type 1* fonts are *never* embedded, hence you need to pick another font.

The example from the tutorial uses the free font FreeSans:

```
public const String FONT = "resources/font/FreeSans.ttf";
```

The font object is defined like this:

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FONT, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true);
```

This font is used in a `Paragraph` like this:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.SetFont(font);
p.Add(new Text("Font is embedded"));
document.Add(p);
```

This is the C# version. If you need the Java version, take a look at the [Java version of the tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-7-creating-pdfua-and-pdfa-documents):

```
public static final String FONT = "src/main/resources/font/FreeSans.ttf";
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.setFont(font);
p.add(new Text("Font is embedded"));
document.add(p);
```

If you already use this approach, and you still get the error, you probably have some content somewhere for which you didn't define a font that is embedded.

Comment: Thanks, as I said, I'm ashamed to no have seen it... Yet, I had read the tutorial a long time ago...